# How To Show Upload Progress jQuery,Ajax,PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple PHP upload form with AJAX and jQuery. And I want to show upload progress.

```
var main = function(e) {
    $("#upload").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#l").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#l").hide();
            },
        });
    }); 
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<form id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="here"></div>
<div id="l" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
<div id="p"></div>
```

How Can I Show Upload Progress?

Comment: need to add timeout so it takes some time to upload image

Comment: Are you using some kind of plugin? Where does `uploadProgress` come from?

Comment: no... i am just using Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are set of options to track the progress of the AJAX call in $(form).ajaxSubmit().

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#upload').submit(function(e) {   
            if($('#userImage').val()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#loader-icon').show();
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
                    target:   '#targetLayer', 
                    beforeSubmit: function() {
                        $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete){ 
                        $("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                        $("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-bar-status">' + percentComplete +' %</div>')
                    },
                    success:function (){
                        $('#loader-icon').hide();
                    },
                    resetForm: true 
                }); 
                return false; 
            }
        });

});
```